# Javascript bind weird bug while using two parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-5

Consider following example

```
export default function App() {
  const newFunction = (valueOne, valueTwo) => {
    console.log('valueOne:', valueOne, 'valueTwo:', valueTwo)
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <button onClick={newFunction.bind(this, 1)}> Bind (single param) </button>
      <br />
      <button onClick={newFunction.bind(this, 1, 2)}>Bind (two params) </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here this React app is having `onClick` event where `newFunction` is called on every click of the button element. To pass the parameter `.bind()` has been used.

Whenever passing two parameters for the `newFunction`, the output is printing in console as expected. ex: `newFunction.bind(this, 1, 2)` outputs to => `valueOne: 1 valueTwo: 2`

Question:
However while passing single parameter `newFunction.bind(this, 1)` the output was wierd as below,

```
valueOne: 1
valueTwo: SyntheticBaseEvent {_reactName: "onClick", _targetInst: null, type: "click", nativeEvent: PointerEvent, target: HTMLButtonElement…}
_reactName: "onClick"
_targetInst: null
type: "click"
nativeEvent: PointerEvent
target: 
<button> Bind (single param) </button>
currentTarget: null
eventPhase: 3
bubbles: true
cancelable: true
timeStamp: 12358.5
defaultPrevented: false
isTrusted: true
view: Window
detail: 1
screenX: 2017
screenY: 328
clientX: 571
clientY: 97
pageX: 571
pageY: 97
ctrlKey: false
shiftKey: false
altKey: false
metaKey: false
getModifierState: ƒ modifierStateGetter() {}
button: 0
buttons: 0
relatedTarget: null
movementX: 0
movementY: 0
isDefaultPrevented: ƒ functionThatReturnsFalse() {}
isPropagationStopped: ƒ functionThatReturnsFalse() {}
preventDefault: ƒ preventDefault() {}
stopPropagation: ƒ stopPropagation() {}
persist: ƒ persist() {}
isPersistent: ƒ functionThatReturnsTrue() {}
<constructor>: "SyntheticBaseEvent"
```

Expected output for `newFunction.bind(this, 1)` should be `valueOne: 1 valueTwo: undefined` as the second parameter is not present. Instead it's behaving in a different way.

Codesandbox URL: https://v12ek.csb.app/ (Go to console tab in developer tools to see the output)

Comment: Event handlers are always passed an `event` parameter.

Comment: @Pointy - could you brief with a small example?

Comment: You posted a perfectly good example. The browser (or your framework) passes your event handlers event objects that describe what kind of event it is, what DOM elements were involved, and so on. That is a fundamental fact of JavaScript programming for web browsers, and has been for over 20 years.

Comment: [Read the opening sentence of this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind). That's why the event parameter comes *after* the parameters fixed with the call to `.bind()`.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy for the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem here is that if you bind just one argument the second one is the click event

```js
const newFunction = (valueOne, valueTwo) => {
    console.log('valueOne:', valueOne, 'valueTwo:', valueTwo)
  };
  
  const fakeEvent = {event: 'click'}
  
 newFunction.bind(this, 1, 2)(fakeEvent) //this works
 
 newFunction.bind(this, 1)(fakeEvent)
 
 newFunction.bind(this, 1, undefined)(fakeEvent) //this works
```

Comment: The event parameter will **always** be passed; it will appear after the last argument established by the `.bind()` call.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug.

Considering `newFunction.bind(this, 1, 2)`,

the arguments that are passed with bind (`1, 2`) and the arguments that are passed when invoking the returned function (`newFunction.bind(this, 1, 2)` returns a function that gets called with the 'click' event when the button gets clicked) are combined and passed to `newFunction`.

You're not seeing the event in the case of `newFunction.bind(this, 1, 2)` because `newFunction` only takes two arguments. If it is modified to take another, you can see the event in this case too.

```
const newFunction = (valueOne, valueTwo, valueThree) => {
    console.log(valueOne, valueTwo, valueThree); // valueThree will be the event
};
```